# SELECT from sql 2 cols in 1 table group by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have some issue with my select statement using 2 cols from 1 table and group the data by date.
The data I have like this screen:

[image: My data]

and The result I want like:

[image: expected result]

any one can help on this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    date_format(date, '%Y-%m-01') date_month,
    sum(`close` > `open`) uptime,
    sum(`close` < `open`) downtime,
    sum(`close` = `open`) equaltime
    stock_id
from mytable
group by date_month, stock_id
```

Note that I added an additional query do count days where `close` is equal to `open`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `right()` to extract month you need from the date

```
select
    right(date, 6) as month,
    sum(case when change > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as up_times,
    sum(case when change < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as down_times,
    stock_id
from yourTable
group by
    right(date, 6),
    stock_id
```